# How to find the largest size of memory?

Tags: memory

how can I calculate the largest size of memory that can be used with a 16 bit address bus and a 8 bit data bus?

Is it 2**16 bytes - with regard to the address bus - or 1 byte - with regard to the data bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the address bus bit count that determines how many **locations** you may pinpoint.

And yes, '2' to the power of 'bits' tells the amount.

In case of a longer read/write (16, 32 or even more bits) the "next" adress required is read.
Note also the difference between small-endian and big-endian CPU's; see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

The data bus size determines how big chunks the CPU will transfer at a time (for one read operation), it doesn't "stop" the ability to read more (e.g. the old M68008 is a 16/32 bit CPU - having fourteen 32bit registers, combined with an 8 bit external data bus - reading/writing 32 bits from/to memory is handled by the internal logic of the CPU - but takes longer as it has to be completed in several memory access operations).

Comment: So even if the data bus size is very much higher (say larger than 2**16), tye address bus size is considere, is that so?

Comment: The data bus determines only how many bits you may transfer in one chunk. Unless there is some very exotic feature(s) in the CPU - I'm not aware of any though. A GPU, a Graphics card "CPU"- may be something that fits the exotic realm.